# Javascript For loop iteration count not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to push a few objects into an array through a for loop. Although, in that for loop I would like the name of the object to be the current iteration of the for loop. The for loop displayed below runs twice, therefore the Name variable for the first object should be 1 and the name for the second object should be 2. But, in this case for whatever reason, both objects in this array return a Name value of 2. Does anyone know why this would happen?

```js
var ThisArray = [];
var ThisObj = {};

for (var x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
  ThisObj.Name = x;
  ThisArray.push(ThisObj);
}

console.log(ThisArray);
```

Comment: Use let x=1, instead of var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always pushing the same object in the array, and so the second iteration will edit also the one that was previously inserted; instead, you should do something like this:

```
var obj= {};
for(let x= 1; x<= 2; x++){
    obj= {};
    obj.name = x;
    arr.push(obj);
}
console.log(arr);
```

so you will change `obj` every iteration

PS: better version:

```
for(let x= 1; x<= 2; x++){
    arr.push({name : 2});
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote it, but I don't have enough points yet.

Answer (score 3):

You always add the same object. Move the object inside the loop:

```js
const thisArray = [];

for (let x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
  const thisObj = {};
  thisObj.Name = x;
  thisArray.push(thisObj);
}

console.log(thisArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply reassigning the value of the `Name` property of the `ThisObj` to a new value. It is a reference, so you need to create a new instance each time you want to add a new item. Move the variable declaration into the `for` loop:

```
var ThisArray= [];
    for(var x= 1; x<= 2; x++){
      var ThisObj= {};
      ThisObj.Name = x;
     
      ThisArray.push(ThisObj);
    }
console.log(ThisArray);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote this as well, but I don't have enough points yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you push twice the same object.

Here is what you want:

```js
var ThisArray = [];
for (var x = 1; x <= 2; x++) {
    var ThisObj = {};
    ThisObj.Name = x;

    ThisArray.push(ThisObj);
}
console.log(ThisArray);
```